# Redis/Jedis not serving properly

Tags: spring, spring-boot, redis, jedis

We are using Redis cache in our Spring Java application with Jedis and during high loads the cache get stuck and not responding in timely fashion.

We have configured the Jedis connection as follows:

```
val clientConfiguration = JedisClientConfiguration
                .builder()
                .readTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(2L))
                .connectTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(10L))
                .usePooling()
                .build()

        val configuration = RedisStandaloneConfiguration(redisHost, Integer.parseInt(redisPort))
        configuration.password = RedisPassword.of(redisPassword)

val jedisConnectionFactory = JedisConnectionFactory(configuration, clientConfiguration)
        jedisConnectionFactory.poolConfig.apply {
            maxTotal = 512
            maxIdle = 256
            minIdle = 16
            maxWaitMillis = 2000L
            blockWhenExhausted = true
        }
```

The Redis server doesn't seem to be under load and doesn't show any errors. Only problem we can see is when using `jstack` that there hundreds of threads stuck in `RedisCache.get`:

```
 java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.cache.RedisCache.get(RedisCache.java:117)
    - waiting to lock <0x00000000c00bd5f8> (a org.springframework.data.redis.cache.RedisCache)
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.execute(CacheAspectSupport.java:381)
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.execute(CacheAspectSupport.java:345)
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheInterceptor.invoke(CacheInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:688)
```

If the server didn't respond correctly, I would expect to see some exceptions, but there absolutely none. Only thing we can see are super slow responses.

Comment: Did you try Redisson java client? it doesn't have such issues

Answer (score -1, accepted):

We found out this is actually caused by a known issue with Jedis implementation:

https://jira.spring.io/projects/DATAREDIS/issues/DATAREDIS-678?filter=allopenissues

Answer (score 0):

The error you are facing is not because that the redis-server is under any load, it is spring-server that get exhausted. In config:

```
jedisConnectionFactory.poolConfig.apply {
            maxTotal = 512
            ...
            ...
            blockWhenExhausted = true
        }
```

It seems that the **jedis-pool is exhausted and blocking new requests**. To minimize this, you can increase the pool-size also check if the decreasing 
`maxWaitMillis = 2000L`, `readTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(2L))` and `connectTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(10L))` does any improvement.